# Set .focus on second last input, not first or last

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have dynamically created inputs via a button, two get created at a time and I'd like the focus to be on the first of the two each time a set is added, so theoretically it'll always be the second last input

I currently use `$('input:text:visible:first').focus();` but is there a way to do this but get the second last?

```
Input1.1
Input1.2

Input2.1
Input2.2

# user creates new input set via button

Input3.1 <---Focus on this one
Input3.2
```

Comment: please share your html and js code

Comment: @AhsanAli That worked! if you want to asnwer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to use `eq(-2).focus();` ([eq() documentation](https://api.jquery.com/eq/)). From there you can read that the argument can be a negative number that represent the next:

> indexFromEnd / Type: Integer / An integer indicating the position of the element, counting backwards from the last element in the set.

I have made a simple example to demostrate his use:

```js
$("#myBtn").click(function()
{
    $('<input value="new">').appendTo(".wrapper");
    $('<input value="new">').appendTo(".wrapper");
    $(".wrapper input").eq(-2).focus();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
  <input type="text" value="input1">
  <input type="text" value="input2">
  <input type="text" value="input3">
  <input type="text" value="input4">
</div>
<button id="myBtn">ADD</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `input:nth-last-child(n)` where n is any number

```js
function createInput() {
  let str = `<div class ='ipCon'>
               <input type='text'>
               <input type='text'>
               <input type='text'>
             </div>`;
  document.getElementById('con').innerHTML = str;
  document.getElementsByClassName('ipCon')[0].querySelector('input:nth-last-child(2)').focus()
}
```

```css
input:focus {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div id='con'>

</div>

<button type='button' onclick='createInput()'> Create Inputs</button>
```